# How to detect ⌘ + something key combos with React

Tags: macos, reactjs, events, keyboard

Evt is a SyntheticEvent here:

```
handleEnterPress(evt){

        if(evt.ctrlKey){
            doSomething();
        }
        //..

}
```

Apparently ⌘+enter does not set evt.ctrlKey here? How do I catch those events then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the reference for [KeyboardEvent on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

`event.metaKey` is probably the event you're after. Check out the example at the bottom of the page linked above.